# Creating non clustered Index for multi table joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written a query by joining multiple tables and with multiple column where condition. As we have large amount of data I need to create index on all these columns. So that query should use this index for better performance. Let me know how to create it for below scenario ?

```
SELECT 
  A.NAME,
  B.SAL,
  C.DATE1 
FROM 
  A 
  INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID 
  INNER JOIN C ON B.ID1 = C.ID1
WHERE 
  A.STATUS1 = '0' 
  AND A.TOTALAMT <> 0 
  AND A.FLAG = 'N' 
  AND B.SAL > 100 
  AND C.DATE1 NOT IN('2008-08-08', '2009-09-09')
```

Comment: SQL Server has a neat little feature that lets you show the estimated query plan for any given query. This query plan also gives hints as to what indexes might be beneficial. While it doesn't hit the spot 100% of the times, it should at least give you some kind of idea about what index you need.

Comment: If you have large no. of insert/update operations on the same data, better not to create indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am tying to say same thing what @Ozren has already written.But i always verify my where condition about which I have written .

**Primary Key**

```
  Table A=ID
  Table B=ID1
  Table C=ID1
  Verify uncessary where condition like 
  i)  when sal>100 then TOTALAMT will always >0 (is it so?)
  ii) what is A.STATUS1 and A.FLAG ?(like when Flag='N' then Status is always='0' 
      you can put such validation while insert And avoid extra where condition.
```

**Non CI**

```
Table A (STATUS1, TOTALAMT, FLAG)
Table B (SAL)
Table C (DATE1)
```

1. Analyze all your proc to check which amonth thee columns are very frequently use in where condition.
2. If FOR example `Flag='N'` is very often use then you can use Filtered Index on this column
3. Also ensure proper data type like `Flag` is char(1) and not varchar etc.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb here would be to include fields in your join clause and sargs.
There is more to it (e.g. clustering, selectivity, covering, including...) but you can get even sub-optimal results that satisfy.

Try creating these indexes:

- Table A (ID)
- Table B (ID, ID1)
- Table C (ID1)

...run and test your application and its database access performance.

If you encounter problems, you may find that something like this perform better:

- Table A (ID, STATUS1, TOTALAMT, FLAG)
- Table B (ID, ID1, SAL)
- Table C (ID1, DATE1)